# Precompiling JSPs in Jenkins CI

Tags: jsp, ant, jenkins

Has anyone called an ant script in Jenkins CI that pre-compiles JSPs using JspC?  I'm trying to migrate my project to use Jenkins and when I call my ant script i keep getting the following exception:

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: file:/demo /workspace/Trunk/src/main/webapp/pages/test.jsp (line: 9, column: 0) The value for the useBean class attribute org.demo.model.UserAccount is invalid.

The ant script has worked fine outside of Jenkins but will not run without error inside of it.  Thoughts?

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt" %>

<jsp:useBean id="User" class="com.demo.model.UserAccount"/>
<c:url var="saveUserUrl" value="/account/save.html" />

<form:form modelAttribute="account" method="POST" action="${saveUserUrl}">  
<form:errors path="*" cssClass="statusError" element="p" htmlEscape="false" />
<form:hidden path="id"/>

    <div style="width:60%"> 
        <fieldset>          
            <p class="field">
                <label for="">First Name</label>
                <form:input path="firstName" title="First name"/>
            </p>            
            <p class="field">
                <label for="">Last Name</label>
                <form:input path="lastName" title="Last name">
            </p>        
            <p class="field">
                <label for="">E-mail Address</label>
                ${account.email}
            </p>
        </fieldset>
        <p class="field">
            <input type="submit" class="button" value="Save" name="submit"/>
        </p>
    </div>  

</form:form>
```

Comment: This is my jsp code.  Ant script works fine outside of Jenkins, but will not run within.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your lib path and includes?  According to the JSP docs, the JSP:UseBean task will try to find the bean in your path first.  If it does find that class, then I don't know if it will pay attention to what you type below that point.  Which declaration of the bean takes precedence? Inline or what it finds in the path?

http://profesores.elo.utfsm.cl/~agv/elo330/2s03/projects/Tomcat/doc/1.2/syntaxref1217.html

Also, it looks like this ant task (JspC) is deprecated as of Tomcat5.
https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/jspc.html

The Ant documentation recommends using the Tomcat task instead of the ant task.
*There are many limitations with this task which partially stem from the many versions of Jasper, others from implementation 'issues' in the task (i.e. nobody's willingness to radically change large bits of it to work around jasper). Because of this and the fact that JSP pages do not have to be portable across implementations -or versions of implementations- this task is better used for validating JSP pages before deployment, rather than precompiling them. For that, just deploy and run your httpunit junit tests after deployment to compile and test your pages, all in one go.*